# Prevent "Stop running script" when loading large amounts of data

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm currently running 2 for-loops, going through 2 arrays of objects and creating a new array with the objects which occur in both lists. When the lists become to large, I get a "Stop running script" prompt.

```
MineGlobals.receivedData = jQuery.parseJSON(MineGlobals.receivedDataRaw);
MineGlobals.nettStasjonsListe = new Array();

var len1 = MineGlobals.nsData.length;
var len2 = MineGlobals.receivedData.Nettstasjoner.length
for (var i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < len1; j++) {
            if (MineGlobals.receivedData.Nettstasjoner[i].Id == MineGlobals.nsData[j].Id) {
                var obj = new nsObject();
                obj = MineGlobals.nsData[j];
                if (MineGlobals.nsData[j].Lg != 0 && MineGlobals.nsData[j].La != 0) {
                    MineGlobals.nettStasjonsListe.push(obj);    
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried with setTimeout(), but can't get it to work... So any ideas?

**EDIT**

So since I am a new user I can't answer my own question but I managed to find the solution. I used a associativeArray(). Placing the largest array in it, with the ID as key, and then iterating over it to find the identical IDs.

```
var associativeArray = {};
for (var i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
    associativeArray[MineGlobals.nsData[i].Id] = MineGlobals.nsData[i];
}

 for (var j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
    var obj = new nsObject();
    obj = associativeArray[MineGlobals.receivedData.Nettstasjoner[j].Id];
    if (obj != undefined) {
        if (obj.Lg != 0 && obj.La != 0) {
            if (obj == null || obj == "") {
                obj.Nvn = "Ikke definert";
            }
            if (obj.NisAdresse == null || obj.NisAdresse == "") {
                obj.NisAdresse = "Ikke definert";
            }
            MineGlobals.nettStasjonsListe.push(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're building an array as the product of two big arrays ? What's the expected size of the resulting array/matrix in bytes ? Are you sure your problem isn't memory related ?

Comment: *I tried with setTimeout()*... how? Using an asynchronous processing queue is one way to solve it. Or web workers...

Comment: This may not help much, but you can give it a try. For your loops, instead of doing a incremental loop, you can try to the do opposite. `for (var j = len1; j > 0; j--)` Because for the interpreter compare one value to zero is much faster than compare one number to another variable. Especially in this case you have two large for loops.

Comment: Are the objects in one of the arrays guaranteedsorted on Id? If yes, use a binary search alogrithm

Answer (score 0):

You can `chunk` the array processing, see the following [link](http://www.mattsnider.com/javascript/handle-slow-processes-without-blocking-the-ui/):

I wrote a prototype class around it and it solved my problem regarding this:

```
/**
 * provides UI update while using large arrays without blocking
 * found core idea on http://www.mattsnider.com/javascript/handle-slow-processes-without-blocking-the-ui/
 */
var ChunkedArray = Class.create(Enumerable, {
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.array = new Array();
        this.options = Object.extend({
            chunkSize: 20,
            interval: 10
        }, options || {})
    },

    push: function(obj) {
        this.array.push(obj)
    },

    chunk: function(array, index, length, iterator, context) {
        var j, l = array.length;
        for (j = (index + length); (index < j && index < l); index += 1) {
            iterator.call(context, array[index], index);
        }

        if (l > index) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                this.chunk(array, index, length, iterator, context);
            }.bind(this), this.options.interval);
        }
    },

    _each: function(iterator, context) {
        this.chunk(this.array, 0,
                this.options.chunkSize, iterator, context);
    },

    toString: function() {
        return this.array.toString();
    }
});
```